# Inserting value to nested lists

Tags: python, insert, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
nums = ['-3.00', '-3.50', '-4.00']
values = [['1.9', ' 2.05'], ['1.97', ' 2.02'], ['2.03', ' 1.95']]
```

For every nested list in `values` I want to insert a number from `nums`.

The desired effect:

```
[['-3.00', '1.9', ' 2.05'], ['-3.50', '1.97', ' 2.02'], ['-4.00', '2.03', ' 1.95']]
```

I came up with:

```
[[row.insert(0, n) for n in nums] for row in values]
```

I wonder why this would not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason why it doesn't work is that the `insert` method returns `None`.

You want this:

```
[[n] + v for n, v in zip(nums, values) ]
```

Comment: Exactly, thanks! Can you think of a reason why my code is messed up?

Comment: Added the reason.  Try `print nums.insert(0,3)`.  Hope it helps!

Comment: @nutship, your code does modify `values` as a sideeffect, but you insert _all_ of the numbers into each value because you have nested the loops instead of using zip. It's not good practice to use list comprehensions for their sideeffects.